# Difference between two NetworkX graphs with different node sets

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want the difference G1-G2 giving an output of edges which exist in G1, but not in G2. The `difference`function in NetworkX allows this difference only when G1 and G2 have same node sets.

My example:
G1.edges=`EdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 18))`

G2.edges=`EdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 22)])`

Desired output is `(1,18)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EdgeView class defines set operations on edges.
Thus, you may simply use:

```
G1.edges() - G2.edges()
```

Example:

```
>>> G2.edges()
EdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 22)])
>>> G1.edges()
EdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 18)])
>>> G1.edges() - G2.edges()
{(1, 18)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above method does not work if the type of G1.edges is 'OutMultiEdgeDataView'

[This](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.difference.html) method (nx.difference(G,H) works irrespective of the type of Edge whether it is EdgeView or MultiEdgeView